# Detecting kick discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I tried to add a functionality to my Discord bot that would detect when some moderator kicks someone and retrieve the kicked user's id. I am thinking of an event like on_message or on_member_join but couldn't find an answer to my question.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is this : https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_remove#discord.on_member_remove

Unfortunately you will not be able to distinguish leaving from kicking or banning. But once a member is kicked, you can then check the logs to see if there was a recent kick https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=logs#discord.Guild.audit_logs

Comment: Could you show me the example?

`@commands.Cog.listener()
  async def on_member_remove(self, member):
    entry = list(await member.guild.audit_logs(limit=1).flatten())[0]`

I'm stuck at this point.

Comment: This entry will be of the type AuditLogEntry https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=logs#discord.AuditLogEntry then you can check if the action ( https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=logs#discord.AuditLogAction ) is "kick", etc etc

Comment: i did this:
`entry = list(await member.guild.audit_logs(limit=1).flatten())[0]
  if str(entry.action) == "AuditLogAction.kick" and entry.target.id == member.id:`
and it works